# Create Rose from 1 ribbon

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves, lighting

Can anyone offer help in creating a rose made out of ribbon in blender? I have attached a picture of what I have in mind.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I don't even know how to do with this with a real ribbon... If you had some kind of instructions for that it might (eventually) help with creating that in Blender.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is the video I watched: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrpCr94Z-gk

Comment: Okay, now you add a _Bézier_ curve object to your scene and in the _Curve Data Properties_ under _Geometry_ you increase the _Extrude_ value a bit until the ribbon is wide enough. Then try do deform the curve as they do in the video by adding control points with `E`, moving and rotating them, adjusting their handles, changing the _Tilt_ and perhaps _Radius_ (sidepanel `N` > _Item_) to recreate what they are doing. Afterwards you could add a bit of thickness with a _Solidify_ modifier.